# Type error when making generic MessageBus in Typescript (with rxjs)

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make a generic MessageBus in Typescript. I want to have some message classes that derive from a parent MessageBusMessage class. Then I want to be able to subscribe to messages of this class, and have messages of this type returned. Strong generic typing all the way.

This is what I have so far:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';

export class MessageBusMessage {
}

export class TestMessage extends MessageBusMessage {
    constructor(public readonly someValue: string) {
        super();
    }
}

export class MessageBus {
    private subject: Subject<MessageBusMessage>;

    constructor() {
        this.subject = new Subject();
    }

    public publish(message: MessageBusMessage) {
        this.subject.next(message);
    }

    public getMessagesOf<T extends MessageBusMessage>(messageType: T): Observable<T> {
        return this.subject.filter( (message) => {
            return (message.constructor as any).name === (messageType as any).name;
        }) as any;
    }
}

const messageBus = new MessageBus();
const subscription = messageBus.getMessagesOf(TestMessage).subscribe(
    (message) => {
        console.log('got test message', message.someValue);
    }
)

messageBus.publish(new TestMessage('some test value'));
```

The problem is inside the message subscription. The type of the message is the constructor type, not the actual object instance type, so I get a type checking error from the Typescript compiler: `Property 'someValue' does not exist on type 'typeof TestMessage'.`

So I can see how the type Observable is wrong for the return type of getMessageOf. But what is the correct type? How do I get a hold of the object instance type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `getMessagesOf<T>` as taking the constructor for `T` rather than an instance of `T`:

```
public getMessagesOf<T extends MessageBusMessage>(messageType: new (...args: any[]) => T): Observable<T>
```

Comment: Yup. That worked. You really helped me a lot here. I've spent hours trying to get this working on my own.